# MS SQL Server Jobs and MySQL Hanging up

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jobs, freeze

Having some difficulties with MS SQL Server 2008 and MySQL.

We have a few jobs that run to export table data out of the ms sql tables and into mysql tables. They run every 5, 15 and 60 minutes.

Recently an issue arose where the job seems to hang without explanation or errors - it just hangs. Have to `service mysql restart`. The only pattern is that it occurs **after** a temp table is created, right before the `INSERT INTO MYSQLINTRANET...table_temp`. This of course doesn't happen every time.

Here's the SP that is run every 5 minutes:

```
EXEC ('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_temp') at MYSQLINTRANET;
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE table_temp LIKE table;') at MYSQLINTRANET;
INSERT INTO MYSQLINTRANET...table_temp SELECT * FROM MSSQLDB.dbo.table;
EXEC ('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table;') at MYSQLINTRANET;
EXEC ('RENAME TABLE table_temp to table;') at MYSQLINTRANET;
```

Any ideas as to what would cause this, or what I could do differently to avoid it from hanging?

**EDIT**

The MS SQL Table `dbo.table` contains appx 32,000 rows, and it seems to hang there randomly on the `INSERT` procedure. Sometimes the `table_temp` gets filled with appx 15,000 rows then hangs, and other times it succeeds.

Comment: A lot of things play role in these type of issues. Are both SQL instances located on the same server or does the transaction occur over the network? There are a lot of steps to check. I would advise enabling extensive logging for both instances.

Comment: They are on separate virtual machine's and the transaction occurs over the network. Other than breaking the job down to multiple steps for each table, what other kind of logging can I enable?

Comment: In these cases, I run wireshark on both machines during the transaction to see if it was to be a network related issue. Other than that, for each step, you can select log to the table and have extra logging.